# pandas.series.diff weird output

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to copy a column as well as converting it to a .diff column. My output currently look like this:

**CURRENT OUTPUT**

```
                                Händelse                 Tid  Bränslenivå (%)  Diesel (l) Difference (%)
0                            Tändning på 2021-08-03 09:54:59               54  779752    <bound method Series.diff of 0       54\n1    ... 
1                             Inloggning 2021-08-03 09:56:24               54  779754    <bound method Series.diff of 0       54\n1    ...
2                            Tändning av 2021-08-03 10:13:35               54  779766    <bound method Series.diff of 0       54\n1    ...
```

As you can see the "difference" column is giving an entire different output than expected and I have no idea why. The "Difference" column is supposed to print the difference between the rows, however it prints the output above... I have managed to duplicate the column using this part of the code:

```
df1['Difference (%)'] = df1['Bränslenivå (%)']
df1['Difference (%)'] = df1.loc[:, 'Bränslenivå (%)'].diff
```

Here is my all relevant code used:

```
import os
from numpy import empty, int64, percentile
import pandas as pd
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
from tkinter import Tk     # from tkinter import Tk for Python 3.x
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import logging
import sys
import pathlib
from datetime import date, datetime

Tk().withdraw()
filepathname1 = askopenfilename()
filepathname2 = askopenfilename()

print("You have chosen to mix", filepathname1, "and", filepathname2)
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", 10)

df1 = pd.read_excel(filepathname1, 'CWA107 Event', na_values=['NA'], skiprows=1, usecols="A, B, D, E, F")
df3 = pd.read_excel(filepathname1, 'CWA107 Event', na_values=['NA'], skiprows=1, usecols="D, F")
df2 = pd.read_excel(filepathname2, na_values=['NA'], skiprows=1, usecols=['Tankad mängd diesel', 'Unnamed: 3']
)


#df3filt = df3[(df3['Bränslenivå (%)'].diff)]
#print(df3)
#df3filt = df3.diff
#print(df3filt)
difdf3 = df3['Bränslenivå (%)'].diff()
df1['Difference (%)'] = df1['Bränslenivå (%)']
df1['Difference (%)'] = df1.loc[:, 'Bränslenivå (%)'].diff
print(df1)
input()
```

The expected output is:

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
                                Händelse                 Tid  Bränslenivå (%)  Diesel (l) Difference (%)
0                            Tändning på 2021-08-03 09:54:59               54  779752    NaN 
1                             Inloggning 2021-08-03 09:56:24               58  779754    4.0
2                            Tändning av 2021-08-03 10:13:35               52  779766   -6.0
```

I'm not sure why the output is as showed but I guess there's a problem with my code.

Hopefully I have provided enough info. Thank you in advance!

Comment: There is missing `()` after `diff` like `diff()`

Comment: Thank you! I totally missed that.

Answer (score 1):

You meant:

```
df1['Difference (%)'] = df1.loc[:, 'Bränslenivå (%)'].diff()
```

`diff` is not a `@property` decorator, thus it needs to be called.

Comment: Hmm, thinking it is typo - [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo)

Comment: @jezrael Yah! wikied